# Probability of rolling 3 dice, getting different numbers on each throw that sum to 10

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a question in probability and I don't know how to solve it.

What is the probability of rolling 3 dice, and getting different numbers on each throw that, in total, sum to 10?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you list the possible winning outcomes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's list all possible outcomes that satisfy the conditions you set for the probability:

- {6,3,1} in any order.
- {5,4,1} in any order.
- {5,3,2} in any order.

So in total, there are: $3\cdot(3P3) = 18$ possible outcomes that satisfy the conditions.

Now, since the number of **all possible outcomes** is $6^3$, it's very clear that $P(A) \frac{18}{6^3} = \frac{18}{216}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{P}(A) = \frac{\#\{(1, 3, 6) + permutations, (1, 4, 5) + permutations, (2, 3, 5) + permutations \} }{6^3} = \frac{18}{216}$